# JOLT - filter nested array

Tags: json, jolt

new to jolt here and have this task that is a bit too much for me.
I have below inputs

```
{
  "Users": [
    {
      "ID": "1",
      "TD": [
        {
          "serial": 112
        }
      ],
      "HD": [
        "FFA",
        "FFB"
      ],
      "LD": "12",
      "PrivateInfo": [
        {
          "InfoId": "ID1-II1",
          "statuses": [
            "ACTIVE"
          ]
        },
        {
          "InfoId": "ID1-II2",
          "statuses": [
            "ACTIVE",
            "INACTIVE"
          ]
        },
        {
          "InfoId": "ID1-II3",
          "statuses": [
            "IN_PROGRESS"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ID": "2",
      "TD": [
        {
          "serial": 156
        }
      ],
      "HD": [
        "FFB"
      ],
      "LD": "65",
      "PrivateInfo": [
        {
          "InfoId": "ID2-II1",
          "statuses": [
            "ACTIVE",
            "SUSPENDED"
          ]
        },
        {
          "InfoId": "ID2-II2",
          "statuses": [
            "ACTIVE",
            "INACTIVE"
          ]
        },
        {
          "InfoId": "ID2-II3",
          "statuses": [
            "IN_PROGRESS"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ID": "3",
      "TD": [
        {
          "serial": 557
        }
      ],
      "HD": [
        "FFA",
        "FFC"
      ],
      "LD": "98",
      "PrivateInfo": [
        {
          "InfoId": "ID3-II1",
          "statuses": [
            "ACTIVE"
          ]
        },
        {
          "InfoId": "ID3-II2",
          "statuses": [
            "ACTIVE"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The ask is, for each `Users` `PrivateInfo`, keep only any `PrivateInfo` that has `statuses` containing **only** `ACTIVE` and nothing else.

If such a `Users` contain non-empty `PrivateInfo`, then keep that User, otherwise, removes that User from the end result.

The end result should look something like this

```
{
  "Users": [
    {
      "ID": "1",
      "TD": [
        {
          "serial": 112
        }
      ],
      "HD": [
        "FFA",
        "FFB"
      ],
      "LD": "12",
      "PrivateInfo": [
        {
          "InfoId": "ID1-II1",
          "statuses": [
            "ACTIVE"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ID": "3",
      "TD": [
        {
          "serial": 557
        }
      ],
      "HD": [
        "FFA",
        "FFC"
      ],
      "LD": "98",
      "PrivateInfo": [
        {
          "InfoId": "ID3-II1",
          "statuses": [
            "ACTIVE"
          ]
        },
        {
          "InfoId": "ID3-II2",
          "statuses": [
            "ACTIVE"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Appreciate a lot for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Users": {
        "*": {
          "PrivateInfo": {
            "*": {
              "statuses": "=join('',@(1,&))" // concatenate the components of the array to get the case with ACTIVE only
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Users": {
        "*": {
          "PrivateInfo": {
            "*": {
              // "@(2,ID)": "&4[@(3,ID)].&",
              "statuses": {
                "ACTIVE": { // filter out by ACTIVE
                  "@2": "&6.@(5,ID).&4[&3]" // group the objects by the ID values under the node of the array "Users"
                    // where &6 going six levels up the tree to reach and get the key literal "Users" 
                },
                "*": { // and vanish the rest
                  "": ""
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    },
  { // add "ID" attributes to each object while making the JSON array of objects 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Users": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "$1": "&3[#3].ID",
            "*": {
              "*": "&4[#4].&2[&1].&",
              "statuses": "&4[#4].&2[&1].&[]" // add array wrapper
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where conditional for `only "ACTIVE"` vs. `others`(*even it might contain "ACTIVE" along with other components* ) used within the **shift** transformation after `"statuses"` array having been processed within a **modify** transformation.

**Edit** : You can convert your transformation spec to the following one, considering your new case :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Users": {
        "*": {
          "PrivateInfo": {
            "*": {
              "statuses": "=join('',@(1,&))"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Users": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2.&1.&", // all elements but "PrivateInfo"
          "PrivateInfo": {
            "*": {
              "statuses": {
                "ACTIVE": {
                  "@2": "&6.&5.&4[&3]"
                },
                "*": {
                  "": ""
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // returns only the objects having "PrivateInfo" array
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Users": {
        "*": {
          "PrivateInfo": {
            "@1": "&3"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: hi Barbaros, appreciate your help, I made a small change to the input JSON and the expected output, could you help with the new spec, please?

Before there was only ID and PrivateInfo at the same level, now I have added TD, HD, LD to the same level as ID and  Private Info

Comment: hi Barbaros, everything looks good except that the end result Users value is array of an array like this [[...]]. should the last spect be "@1": "&3" instead of "@1": "&3[#2]" ?

Comment: yes exactly @Nathan , seems I missed the part, fixed.